# append HTML elements inside a specific div using Cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to append an HTML text to an HTML file using cheerio. Specifically to add a navigation bar. However whenever the function is called, and I open the HTML file to see if the navigation bar is appended, there are nothing. can anyone help?

```
var addNavBarW3CSS = function(){
    let readManipulateFileName = 'generated_web/'+fileNameChosen+'.html';
    const $ = cheerio.load(fs.readFileSync(readManipulateFileName,'utf8'));
    var navText="";
    rl.question("Please enter Navigation Text: \n",function(answer) {
            navText='<a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:25% !important">'+answer+'</a>';
            $('#navItem1').append(navText);
            console.log(navText+" succesfully appended to navigation");
            createMobileWebPageSubmenu();
        });
    }
```

The div element inside different file that im trying to append. Basically the navigation bar file

```
<!-- Navbar on small screens (Hidden on medium and large screens) -->
<div class="w3-top w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium">
  <div class="w3-bar w3-black w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off w3-center w3-small" id="navItem1">
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:25% !important">HOME</a>
    <a href="#about" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:25% !important">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="#photos" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:25% !important">PHOTOS</a>
    <a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:25% !important">CONTACT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you expecting the contents of `generated_web/'+fileNameChosen+'.html` to have changed?  I don't see you saving it, just reading it.

Comment: Im trying to write on $('#navItem1').append(navText);. Because Im trying to refer to specific div element. Is there any other method you can recommend? @James

Comment: Yeah but that just updates the in-memory document, it doesn't convert it to html and write it to a file.  If that's what you are trying to do (?)

Comment: @James How do I write it to the HTML file, since I need to point to a specific div? I have figured out how to convert by using ```$('#navItem1').append(navText).html(); ``` and when I console.log() the result it shows that the children element is appended. Should I try to search up on how to replace the all the children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the cheerio output to a file after making changes to the cheerio document.

This example overwrites readManipulateFileName file with the new content from cheerio.  If you don't want to overwrite you can put a different filename.

```js
var addNavBarW3CSS = function(){
    let readManipulateFileName = 'generated_web/'+fileNameChosen+'.html';
    const $ = cheerio.load(fs.readFileSync(readManipulateFileName,'utf8'));
    var navText="";
    rl.question("Please enter Navigation Text: \n",function(answer) {
            navText='<a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:25% !important">'+answer+'</a>';
            $('#navItem1').append(navText);
            console.log(navText+" succesfully appended to navigation");
            createMobileWebPageSubmenu();
            
            // once all the changes to $ are complete:
            fs.writeFileSync(readManipulateFileName, $.html(), 'utf8');
    });
}
```

Based on [How to put scraping content to html (Node.js, cheerio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963389/how-to-put-scraping-content-to-html-node-js-cheerio)
and
[Writing to file after modifying with cheerio on node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54545117/writing-to-file-after-modifying-with-cheerio-on-node)

Comment: Hi thanks for the tips really appreciate it man, I've found the solution and post it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've found an answer to my problem here is it and put it some comment in it.

```
var addNavBarW3CSS = function(){

        let readManipulateFileName = 'generated_web/'+fileNameChosen+'.html';
        const $ = cheerio.load(fs.readFileSync(readManipulateFileName,'utf8'));

        var navText="";


        rl.question("Please enter Navigation Text: \n",function(answer) {
            navText='<a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:25% !important">'+answer+'</a>';
            //to append new element
            $('#navItem1').append(navText).html();
            //to make the cheerio object whole HTML again
            navHTML=$("*").html();
            //to write to the HTML file again
            fs.writeFileSync(readManipulateFileName, navHTML, 'utf8');
            
            

            console.log(navHTML);
            createMobileWebPageSubmenu();
        });
'''
```